# How to change the position of transfer icons in telerik listbox Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

How to change the position of transfer icons in telerik list box Control from the right of the list box to the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve it using the following line of code:

lbAvailableRoles.ButtonSettings.Position = ListBoxButtonPosition.Left;